# Game getting stuck

Tags: python

I'm following a Python course on Udemy.com and we are practicing Python by building an RPG game. So far the game was working fine for a single player but as soon as we added 3 players the game seems to just get stuck after executing all 3 players attacks.

*The concept is that there are 3 players or so, as the game starts the player stats are shown, after all the players have attacked each other this includes the enemy as well, the player stats are printed as shown below in the picture and the game asks for input from all the three players again, but it's just running once as shown below in the picture.*

I followed the code for word to word and also posted a question regarding it. So I thought I should try StackoverFlow.
Below is my code kindly see why is it not going in loop as it should.

**Mainfile**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from game_class.invin import Item
from game_class.game import player
from game_class.magic import Spell
import time

# Player and Enemies magic create
Fire_Shot = Spell('Fire Shot', 10, 45, "Black Magic")
Thunder_Storm = Spell("Thunder Storm",25,65,"Black Magic")
Ninja_Summon = Spell("Ninja Summon",45,75,"Ninjustu")
The_End = Spell("THE END",80,300,"Finisher")
Heal = Spell("HEAL ME",60,140,'Heal')


player_magic = [Fire_Shot,Thunder_Storm,Ninja_Summon,Heal,The_End]


enemy_magic = [
    {'Name': "Big Punch", 'cost': 30, "DMG": 45},
    {'Name': "Slap", 'cost': 15, "DMG": 25},
    {'Name': "Rock Throw", 'cost': 20, "DMG": 30},
    {'Name': "Kick", 'cost': 45, "DMG": 60}
]


boss_magic = [
    {'Name': "STORM", 'cost': 10, "DMG": 45},
    {'Name': "DARK BACK-BITTING", 'cost': 10, "DMG": 25},
    {'Name': "D.D.T", 'cost': 10, "DMG": 30}
]


# Items create
potion = Item("Potion", 'Potion', 'Heals for 50 HP', 50)
high_potion = Item("Potion+", 'Potion', 'Heals for 120 HP', 120)
super_potion = Item("Ultra Potion", 'Potion', 'Heal for 250 HP', 250)
elixir = Item("Elixir", 'Elixir', 'Give 1 EVERYTHING BACK', 9000)
high_elixir = Item("Omega Elixir", 'Elixir', 'Give all  EVERYTHING BACK', 9000)
bomb = Item("Bomb",'Attack','Deals 350 Damage',350)

player_items = [ {"item":potion,"quantity":3},
    {'item':high_potion,"quantity":2}
    ,{"item":super_potion,"quantity":1}
    ,{'item':elixir,"quantity":2}
    ,{'item':high_elixir,"quantity":1}
    ,{"item": bomb, "quantity": 2} ]


# PLAYER CREATE
Player1 = player('Night Man  ',1000, 100, 145, 140, player_magic, player_items)
Player2 = player('Ray Wills  ', 1000, 100, 155, 135, player_magic, player_items)
Player3 = player("Randy Orton",1000, 100, 150, 120, player_magic, player_items)
Enemy1 = player("Door Keeper",1500, 200, 250, 150, enemy_magic, None)
BOSS = player("Boss Man",1200, 200, 45, 300, boss_magic, None)


players = [Player1,Player2,Player3]



# Game starts

run = True
i = 1

while run is True:
    print ("=======================================")
    print("\n\n")

    print("  NAME                        HP                                 MP\n")

    for player in players:
        player.get_stats()


    for player in players:

        print("\n")
        player.chose_action()
        print("=========\n")
        print (player.name)
        print ("=============")
        choice = input("CHOSE ACTION: ")
        index = int(choice) - 1


        if index == 0:
            dmg = player.gen_dmg()
            Enemy1.get_dmg(dmg)
            print(player.name+ " attacked for " + str(dmg) + " damage points")



        elif index == 1:
            player.chose_magic()
            magic_choice = (int(input("Chose Spell: ")) - 1)

            spell = player.magic[magic_choice]
            magic_dmg = spell.gen_spell_dmg()
            current_mp = player.get_mp()
            if magic_choice == -1:
                continue


            if spell.cost > current_mp:
                print ("\nNOT ENOUGH MANA")
                continue

            if spell.stype == "Heal":
                player.heal(magic_dmg)
                print (str(magic_dmg) +' HP restored')
                print("Remaining Magic Points: " + str(player.get_mp()) +
                    "/" + str(player.get_max_mp()))


            elif spell.stype == "Black Magic" or spell.stype == "Ninjustu" or spell.stype == "Finisher":
                player.reduce_mp(spell.cost)
                Enemy1.get_dmg(magic_dmg)
                print (str(spell.name) + ' did damage of '+ str(magic_dmg) +" points")
                print ("Remaining Magic Points: " + str(player.get_mp()) +"/" +str(player.get_max_mp()))

        elif index == 2:
            player.chose_item()
            item_choice = (int(input("Chose Spell: ")) - 1)
            if item_choice == -1:
                continue

            item = player.items[item_choice]['item']
            if player.items[item_choice]['quantity'] == 0:
                print("No Item...")
                continue
            player.items[item_choice]['quantity'] -= 1


            if item.itype == 'Potion':
                player.heal(item.prop)
                print("\n"+ str(item.name) + " used and healed for "+ str(item.prop) + " HP")
            elif item.itype == "Elixir":
                player.hp = Player1.maxhp
                player.mp = Player1.maxmp
                print ("\n"+"STATS RESTORED BECASUE OF " +str(item.name))
            elif item.itype == "Attack":
                Enemy1.get_dmg(item.prop)
                print ("You used a Bomb & that dealt damage of: " + str(item.prop))

    enemy_choice = 1
    enemy_dmg = Enemy1.gen_dmg()
    Player1.get_dmg(enemy_dmg)


    print("========================================")
    print("\n")
    print ("ENEMY ATTACKED YOU FOR " + str(enemy_dmg) + " POINTS")
    print ("ENEMY HP: "+str(Enemy1.get_hp()) +'/'+ str(Enemy1.get_maxhp()))


    if Enemy1.get_hp() == 0:
        print('')
        print ('ENEMY DEAD')
        run = False
    elif Player1.get_hp() == 0:
        print('')
        print('YOU DIED')
        run = False


    elif index == 3:
        print("Arigato Gozaimasu for playing")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("BYE BYE")
        run = False
```

**invin.py**

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name,itype,desc,prop):
        self.name = name
        self.itype = itype
        self.desc = desc
        self.prop = prop
```

**magic.py**

```py
import random

class Spell():
    def __init__(self, name, cost,dmg,stype):
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost
        self.dmg = dmg
        self.stype = stype


    def gen_spell_dmg(self):
        low = self.dmg - 15
        high = self.dmg + 10
        return random.randrange(low,high)
```

**game.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from .magic import Spell
import random



class player:
    def __init__(self,name, hp , mp , atk  ,df ,magic,items):
        self.hp = hp
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
        self.mp = mp
        self.magic = magic
        self.df = df
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.atkH = atk + 25
        self.atkL= atk - 10
        self.actions=['Attack',"Magic","Items"]
        self.maxmp = mp + 10

    def gen_dmg(self):
        return random.randrange(self.atkL,self.atkH)


    def get_dmg(self,dmg):
        self.hp -= dmg
        if self.hp < 0:
            self.hp = 0
        return self.hp


    def get_hp(self):
        return self.hp

    def get_maxhp(self):
        return self.maxhp


    def get_max_mp(self):
        return self.maxmp

    def get_mp(self):
        return self.mp


    def reduce_mp(self,cost):
        self.mp -= cost


    def spell_cost(self, i):
        return self.magic[i]["cost"]


    def chose_action(self):
        print ("Actions")
        print ("===========")
        i = 1
        for item in self.actions:
            print("  " + str(i)+":" + str(item))
            i += 1

    def chose_magic(self):
        print ("Spells")
        print ("===========")
        i = 1
        for spell in self.magic:
            print ("        " + str(i) + ": " + str(spell.name) +  str( " (Cost: " + str ( spell.cost ) +")" ) )
            #the 3rd str helps to print it without the brackets
            i += 1


    def chose_item(self):
        print ("Items")
        print ("===========")
        i = 1
        for item in self.items:
            print("        " + str(i) + ": " +
                  str(item['item'].name) + str(" (" + str(item['item'].desc) + ") ") + " (x"+str(item['quantity'])+")")
            #the 3rd str helps to print it without the brackets
            i += 1


    def heal(self,dmg):
        self.hp += dmg




    def get_stats(self):
        hp_bar = ''
        bar_ticks = ( (self.hp/self.maxhp) * 100 ) / 4

        mp_bar = ''
        mp_bar_ticks = ( (self.mp/self.maxmp) * 100 ) / 10

        while bar_ticks > 0:
            hp_bar += '█'
            bar_ticks -= 1
        while len(hp_bar) < 25:
            hp_bar = " "

        while mp_bar_ticks > 0:
            mp_bar += '▒'
            mp_bar_ticks -= 1
        while len(mp_bar) < 10:
            mp_bar = " "

        hp_string = str(self.hp) + "/"+str(self.maxhp)
        current_hp = ''
        if len(hp_string) < 9:
            decreased = 9 - len(hp_string)
            while decreased > 0:
                current_hp += ' '
                decreased -= 1
            current_hp += hp_string
        else:
            current_hp = hp_string




        mp_string = str(self.mp) +"/"+str(self.maxmp)
        current_mp = ''
        if len(mp_string) < 9:
            mp_decreased = 9 - len(mp_string)
            while mp_decreased > 0:
                current_mp += ' '
                mp_decreased -= 1
            current_mp += mp_string
        else:
            current_mp = mp_string



        print("                                _________________________           __________")
        print(str(self.name) + "          " + str(hp_string) +
              " |"+ hp_bar+"| " + str(mp_string) + " |"+mp_bar+"|")
```

The game is an RPG replica and it works by using while loop.

Each player gets a turn and then the player stats are shown after all 3 players have attacked.

[This is how the loop should show player stats after all 3 players attacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM5LO.png)

[But I'm getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDcBN.png)

Comment: Can you show us the output?

Comment: Start with [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what is the 'expectation n reality'? explain your game too (gameplay for general audience)

Comment: The concept is that there are 3 players, as the game starts the player stats are shown, after all the players have attacked each other this includes the enemy as well, the player stats are printed again and the game asks for input from all the three players again, but it's just running once.

Comment: @NemPlayer check updated ver

Comment: `while len(hp_bar) < 25:
        hp_bar = " "` -> This seems to run forever (in game.py -> player -> get_stats)

Comment: @NemPlayer it will replace the hp bar with blank space so that it looks like a proper game.

Comment: @Zayn In the while loop, you are constantly checking if `len(hp_bar)` is less than 25, and if you set it to be `hp_bar = " "`, it's length will be 1 constantly meaning that it would be stuck in the while loop forever.

Comment: @NemPlayer You are a genius man. can you post this as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we compare the "[This is how the loop should show player stats after all 3 players attacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM5LO.png)" and "[But I'm getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDcBN.png)" screenshots, we can see, by looking at the code, that the issue is caused on the second run of `player.get_stats()`. This method is defined in the `game.py` file.

Inside the method we can see the following 2 lines of code:

```
while len(hp_bar) < 25:
    hp_bar = " "
```

If the while-loop ever gets to run, it will be stuck forever. This is because if `len(hp_bar) < 25` is `True`, the code does `hp_bar = " "`, which in turns makes `len(hp_bar)` to be equal to 1 now. This now gets the while loop to check if `len(hp_bar) < 25` again, which returns `True` (as `len(hp_bar)` is `1`) so the while-loop runs again. This creates an endless loop.